# Load balancing LDAP from a Domain Controller via F5

Tags: windows, active-directory, load-balancing

I know that load balancing or fail over of LDAP on a Windows domain controller is generally not a good idea due to the Kerberos and SPN issues.

BUT, I have lots of non-windows applications that use LDAP for authentication and authorization. They are just pointed to a single domain controller right now, would be nice to have a VIP and a pool with all my DC's behind it.

So whats the deal here when I see this?:

https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/ad-dcs-behind-f5

Does the F5 do something special? Does it just fall back to NTLM? Or does it just use a simple LDAP bind to AD? (or SLDAP bind).

Whats the best way for non-windows clients to utilize LDAP? Should they just be designed out of the box to use the DNS locator SRV records? Should AD-LDS be deployed and load balance that?

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, applications who want to interact with Active Directory really *should* be designed to use proper DC location procedures (which are well documented); unfortunately, quite often they aren't.

You can usually work around this by pointing your LDAP application to the Active Directory domain name instead of a specific DC, because each DC automatically registers AN A record for the domain name pointing to its IP address, so this will work as a DNS round robin; however, this can and will cause two significant issues:

- If a DC is down, it will still be included in the DNS answer; this could cause LDAP failures if the application isn't smart enough to try another one.
- This will not take into any account the Active Directory site topology; if you have a geographically distributed environment, you could end up with an application in London authenticating against a DC in Australia over a slow and/or unreliable WAN link.

A slightly better solution is to create your own DNS record for LDAP applications as a CNAME record pointing to a specific DC, such as `ldap.example.com` pointing to `dc1.example.com`, and set a slow TTL on it (f.e. 60 seconds); you can then configure your application to use `ldap.example.com` for all its LDAP needs. If/when DC1 goes down, you can then remap `ldap.example.com` to `dc2.example.com`, and the slow TTL will ensure the application becomes aware of the change as soon as possible, thus minimizing downtime.

In any case, it's really better to avoid load balancing solution, because LDAP is simply not designed to work with them and they could load to any sort of issues.

Comment: I see, good info. How about if its a simple authentication, using name/password and employing session-level encryption? I assume thats why its working OK with an F5 since Kerberos is not being used at all? Are there any issues with that other than its not the best in terms or security?

Comment: That's not a security issue... that's a protocol issue; LDAP is just not designed to work with load balancing. Microsoft doesn't support it, and so doesn't anyone (up to and including F5). It may very well be possible that everything works fine in 99% of situations, but whenever something will inevitably go wrong, absolutely nobody will support you if you've placed a load balancer in front of your domain controllers, and you will *not* be able to rule out if your problem it's actually caused by it or by something completely unrelated. **TL;DR: You are just asking for troubles.**

Comment: How about something like this: http://windowsitpro.com/article/network-load-balancing-nlb/load-balance-ad-lds-with-microsoft-nlb-in-6-steps-102360 and sync LDS with AD.

Comment: We have successfully used a F5 LDAP load balancer with Active Directory for nearly a decade.  The key is that the usage must be for genuine LDAP-based applications.  You say non-Windows so there you go - the application just wants a LDAP directory.  It is not Kerberos nor NTLM nor anything to do with AD.  Just listen on 389 and optionally 636 and it just works.  We use a virtual server DNS A record and just point to the virtual IP address.  If you do choose to use encryption, then the application should either not worry about mismatched names or you'll have to deal with the certificates.

Comment: Exactly, these are just apps that do a simple LDAP bind using certs for TLS. I see some other posts like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803408/load-balancing-redundancy-for-windows-domain-controllers-for-ldap-ldaps-only. Would simple LDAP binds be problematic with AD? I assume its not using NTLM or Kerberos if you are just performing a simple bind under TLS/SSL?

Comment: Nice idea. The same premise here can also be used to work around the multi site / slow link issue.. A couple A records can be pointed to a specific site's AD servers. Wish I had come up with that years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of the non windows LDAP authentication products I've seen are capable of using a DNS entry. Instead of pointing to a specific server you can point to the root of your domain. This should work in the vast majority of situations.

This is teh case because if you do a lookup at the root of your domain e.g. example.com it should come back with all of the IPs of your domain controllers. This allows for standard round robin DNS to take over, without needing any kind of specialised setup.

Answer (score 1):

Is this more about high availability or performance?

For performance, I want to highlight this:

> I have lots of non-windows applications that use LDAP for authentication and authorization. They are just pointed to a single domain controller right now.

The obvious quick solution here is to point some of your applications at your additional DCs. Of course, this isn't ideal because it leaves applications vulnerable if a DC goes down, but it is any easy way to help spread out your load right away.

For high availability, you can point applications at the domain name or (even better) a cname of the domain name. It's not great, because it means a manual dns adjustment if something goes wrong, but it will make it easier to respond.

You can combine these techniques by using cname records to multiple DCs. The load is spread out, and you can easily adjust a cname record for an individual DC in the event of an outage.

Answer (score 1):

One challenge with using a load balancer is, depending on the activity, some applications may request a handle to a DirectoryEntry.  The DirectoryEntry includes the server name. This is more common for updates, but may also occur for reads/queries. Obviously you are not going through the load balancer in that case. Would it be good enough for authentication? Maybe.

I have learned that if you make a service available, people may use it for other than what you intend. So that "authentication only" VIP you setup?  Maybe someone decides to use it for something else.  That is really important.  What happens if it blows up?

Another issue is what are the health checks?  It isn't uncommon for a domain controller to be up on port 389/636 but not functioning correctly. So a straight up port check may not be good enough.

Traditionally, Active Directory connection resiliency (the DC Locator process) is pushed down to the client.  When you start tinkering with it to make it "highly available", you take ownership of issues. And some of those issues may be difficult and elusive to diagnose and resolve.  Who will support you?  F5?  Microsoft?  Good luck with that.

Comment: So what it boils down to is making sure the app can handle failover, ie - you can enter more than one hostname for the domain controller, OR, the app can handle the domain controller locator process. Load balancing LDAP is at your own risk.

Comment: That is the upshot, yes.  Relying on a straight DNS lookup is a common mistake when attempting to utilize Active Directory. I've seen this mistake even with very common commercial products.

Comment: A true LDAP application does not use DC Locators as they are not integrating with Active Directory; they are just LDAP clients. A few advanced applications are capable of using DNS SRV records but that does not mean they'll use the AD-registered ones; they may have a their own requirements.

Comment: @user339468: The application does not need to use a full blown DC locator.  It could be something as simple as specifying multiple domain controllers in the configuration, and using an alternate if one fails. It isn't rocket science to recognize that only using one domain controller or relying on a straight DNS lookup is a flawed design.

Comment: @Greg Askew: my point was a lot of folks are trying to compare Windows native usage of AD vs simple LDAP clients and a lot of the comparisons (such as DC Locator) are not relevant.  You're right that many LDAP applications support at least two servers.  You can also use round robin DNS which is what AD does natively to load balance.

Comment: Round robin DNS would also be a failed/flawed design.  Just because a record exists in DNS doesn't mean that the host is functional.  The application owns fault tolerance and recovery.  It doesn't matter if the recovery strategy is called DC Locator or Trailer-Park Locator.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 servers in a VIP for that circumstance.

Also, using the domain name is often bad because it will hit the first DC in the list returned, if the application is not site aware (most are not). That could be anywhere in the country and that would be bad for WAN load and latency.

Answer (score 0):

We tried using a DNS round-robin as well.  The problem with that is: Most applications look up the configured LDAP hostname once, grab the first IP that comes back, and then cache that IP.  That means that all LDAP lookups from that application end up going to the same LDAP server every time, defeating the purpose of the round-robin.  We have tried a couple of different load balancer setups, with mixed results.  We are currently trying the Kemp LoadMaster free edition.  So far, it seems to work pretty well with our internal apps, but one particular application (JAMF) ran into a lot of problems when trying to pass LDAP queries through our firewall, even though the firewall is configured properly.